# How safe it is to sort a mixed datatype vector based on the integer value included in datatype using std::sort?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, c++11, mixed

I wrote the following code in Qt creator. I was trying to sort a vector that contains mixed type with 2 QStrings and an integer. I used std::sort and its function mechanism to sort. At least in the output pre-sorting and post-sorting, it seems the sorting worked, but my question is, accurate and safe could it be?

Thanks.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <QDebug>

class mixed
{
public:
    int number;
    QString name;
    QString address;
    mixed(int n, QString s, QString a)
    {
        number = n;
        name = s;
        address = a;
    }

};

bool myfunction (mixed i,mixed j) { return (i.number<j.number); }

int main()
{
    std::vector<mixed>myV;
    myV.push_back(mixed(100, "akkas", "100"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(2, "akkas1", "2"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(1111, "akkas2", "1111"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(-1, "akkas3", "-1"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(7, "akkas4", "7"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(0, "akkas0", "0"));

    for(int i=0; i<myV.size(); i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<myV.at(i).number<<" "<<myV.at(i).name<<" "<<myV.at(i).address<<endl;
    }
    std::sort (myV.begin(), myV.end(), myfunction);

    for(int i=0; i<myV.size(); i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<myV.at(i).number<<" "<<myV.at(i).name<<" "<<myV.at(i).address<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is safe and accurate. You can use lambda expression to avoid writing the `myfunction` as a separate function.

Comment: What you do makes sense and looks good.

Comment: If you don't want to preserve order of equal elements, it is fine. Aside from that, do you need a copy there, in myfunction?

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek Why would I need a copy in that function? I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: @the_naive, sorry for not being clear. You have mixed i, j as your function arguments. It  can possibly slow down your sorting, because at every comparison it copies elements that are to be compared. You probably would like const mixed& i, const mixed& j. You don't modify anything, thus they const refs, and it avoids copying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::sort` can sort elements of any type so long as they're either copyable or movable. The comparison function provided must induce a *strict weak ordering.* Your comparison function is a valid strict weak ordering, which lumps all objects with equal `number` into a single equivalence class. If the unsorted vector contains records with equal `number` values, they will be adjacent in the sorted vector, but the order is unspecified.